# Ninject Overriding Bindings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

From the tutorial referenced below, there is a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  MvcNinjectExample.Logging.ILogger _logger;

  public HomeController(MvcNinjectExample.Logging.ILogger logger)
  {
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    _logger.LogMessage("Running index page!");

    return Content("Message logged");
  }
}
```

As per the following binding...

```
public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<TextFileLogger>();
}
```

... The **TextFileLogger()** is called whenever the `HomeController` is instantiated.  Correct?

The tutorial goes on to say this:

> If you were to change this to use our EventFileLogger implementation as in one of the earlier examples, you will see that all you would have to do is create the implementation, make it implement ILogger and then register it in your kernel bindings. **No changes to any controllers which use it are necessary.**

#### My question is:

If I created a new class called `EventFileLogger()` which implemented `ILogger` and then created the binding like `kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<EventFileLogger>();`, how does Ninject know to use my new `EventFileLogger()` and not the other binding for `TextFileLogger()` when the `HomeController` is instantiated?

Ref. http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/dependency-injection-beginners-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood.

Ninject cannot (by default) decide which concrete class to use given two identical bindings. It does, however, support contextual bindings. For example, you can have `TextFileLogger` injected into your `HomeController` and another concrete implementation somewhere else... but only when you explicitly state such requirements.

The author means that, if you *change* the binding (that is, edit the `To<>()` part), it will all magically continue working with whatever you put there that implements `ILogger`.

Comment: But what if I want to use `TextFileLogger` in one controller and `EventFileLogger` in another controller?  Or, what if I want to use both in the same controller?  Both would still require bindings to `ILogger` right?

Comment: Of course.. however that is where contextual bindings come in. For example, `Bind<ILogger>().To<TextFileLogger>().WhenInjectedInto<HomeController>();` and another `.WhenInjectedInto<>()` for another implementation. Then Ninject knows what to do for each.

Comment: I see, so that seems to be the answer to the question:  The bindings must be changed to a "contextual binding" which specifies when to add what.  Thanks for your help!